# How to access all elements of an orderedlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a list by accessing elements from an array randomly(Using JavaScript, used this link [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)) and then print them all (in first div). Now in another div I want to access that all elements but I am getting results like LI,BR etc. whatever i mentioned when i appended elements to div.(I used this link [Get all elements nested in UL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084153/get-all-elements-nested-in-ul-tag) )

Here the code is:

```
<div   id="list1" >
                        <ol id="olMediators">

                         </ol>
                    </div>
```

For random accessing I am using function

```
function getRandomNumber()
    {

    var items= ["Mediator 1","Mediator 2","Mediator 3", "Mediator 4","Mediator 5","Mediator 6","Mediator 7","Mediator 8","Mediator 9"];

    var newitems=[];
        for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];


        $("#olMediators").append('<li>'+item+'</li>'+'<br/>' );


     }
    }
```

And for print them to another div I am using jquery (Onclick on button):

```
$('#getMediators').click(function(){

                $('#radioMediators').hide();

               var el = document.getElementById("olMediators").getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
                 alert(el[i].tagName);
                }
```

So what I did wrong??
How can I get these all elements and print them to some other place(In different div)??

Thanks

Comment: `br` isn't a valid element within `ol` elements, only `li` is. You're also mixing JavaScript and jQuery unnecessarily, you'd benefit from http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: I checked with jquery and javascript code also but it is not working. Any guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pure jquery solution:

```
$('#getMediators').click(function(){
    $('#radioMediators').hide();
    $("#olMediators li").each(function(){
       alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDkzs/2/)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter did :)

Comment: lol, I was thinking telling the OP what he was doing wrong (as it was part of their question)... but +1 for the update nonetheless :)

Comment: @Hiral: Is this working?? Here it is not working.I checked with both pure jquery and pure javascript code. Both are showing same output. Something missed??

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#getMediators').click(function () {

    $('#radioMediators').hide();

    var el = $('#olMediators *').get();
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        alert(el[i].tagName);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BDkzs/)